# How to get the highest appearance value in one table, from another table?

Tags: sql, join

So I have 3 tables referencing cars, assurance and accident.
I want to know the brand of vehicles who had the most accidents, compared to others.

I have tried a lot of ways to that, but mostly i only get or all the brands returned or the brand of the car that was registered the most, not the one that had most accidents

These are my tables

```
create table car(
    n_veic bigint not null,
    matric varchar(15) not null,
    pais_matric text not null,
    n_pess bigint not null,
    tipo text not null,
    cor text not null,
    brand text not null,
    modelo varchar(15),
    primary key(n_veic),
    unique(matric),
    foreign key (n_pess) references pessoa(n_pess)
);

create table ensurance(
    apolice bigint not null,
    segurado bigint not null,
    car bigint not null,
    datai date not null,
    dataf date not null,
    cobertura numeric(10,2) not null,
    primary key(apolice),
    unique(segurado, veiculo),
    foreign key (segurado) references pessoa(n_pess),
    foreign key (car) references car(n_veic)
);  

create table accident(
    n_acid bigint not null,
    pess_segura bigint not null,
    veic_seguro bigint not null,
    data date not null,
    local varchar(255) not null,
    descr text not null,
    primary key(n_acid),
    unique(n_acid, veic_seguro),
    foreign key (pess_segura,veic_seguro) references ensurance(segurado, car)
```

This is what i tried

```
SELECT marca
FROM veiculo NATURAL JOIN acidente
GROUP BY marca
HAVING count (distinct n_veic)>=ALL
    (SELECT count (distinct n_veic)
    FROM veiculo NATURAL JOIN acidente
    GROUP BY marca);
```

Comment: so you actually want the brand(s) that had the highest percentage of accidents, in the pool of registrations. 1000 fords registered, 200 accidents, accident rate 20%, 1 tesla registered, 1 tesla accident, 100% of teslas have been crashed.. teslas crash 5 times more than fords, right?

Comment: on what i have tried veiculo is car, marca is brand and acident is accident

Comment: What is `marca`? It is not a column in `veiculo`.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS What parts can you do? Where do you get stuck combining them? PS The parts of this are faqs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the logic is:

```
select c.marca, count(*) as num_acidentes
from acidente a join
     car c
     on a.veic_seguro = c.n_veic
group by c.marca
order by num_acidentes desc;
```

You can use `fetch first 1 row only` -- or whatever is appropriate for your database -- to get only one row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

Note:
1. Try to avoid NATURAL JOIN and use specific column reference.
2. Rethink DISTINCT for count is really necessary or not.

```
SELECT TOP 1 marca, COUNT(DISTINCT n_veic) 
FROM veiculo 
NATURAL JOIN acidente 
GROUP BY marca
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT n_veic) DESC
```

Comment: Always avoid natural join; prefer USING or ON and specify columns to join

Comment: Yes that should be @CaiusJard